# Implementing Attention in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to implement attention in keras over a simple lstm:

```
model_2_input = Input(shape=(500,))
#model_2 = Conv1D(100, 10, activation='relu')(model_2_input)
model_2 = Dense(64, activation='sigmoid')(model_2_input)
model_2 = Dense(64, activation='sigmoid')(model_2)

model_1_input = Input(shape=(None, 2048))
model_1 = LSTM(64, dropout_U = 0.2, dropout_W = 0.2, return_sequences=True)(model_1_input)
model_1, state_h, state_c = LSTM(16, dropout_U = 0.2, dropout_W = 0.2, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)(model_1) # dropout_U = 0.2, dropout_W = 0.2,


#print(state_c.shape)
match = dot([model_1, state_h], axes=(0, 0))
match = Activation('softmax')(match)
match = dot([match, state_h], axes=(0, 0))
print(match.shape)

merged = concatenate([model_2, match], axis=1)
print(merged.shape)
merged = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(merged)
print(merged.shape)
model = Model(inputs=[model_2_input , model_1_input], outputs=merged)
adam = Adam()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am getting the error in line:

```
merged = concatenate([model_2, match], axis=1)
```

> 'Got inputs shapes: %s' % (input_shape)) ValueError: A `Concatenate`
>   layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis.
>   Got inputs shapes: [(None, 64), (16, 1)]

The implementation is very simple, just take dot product of lstm output and with the hidden states and use it as weighing function to compute the hidden state itself.

How to resolve the error? Especially how to get the attention concept working?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Reshape layer before concatenating to ensure compatibility.
see keras documentation [here](https://keras.io/layers/core/).
Probably best to reshape the model_2 output `(None, 64)`

**EDIT:**

Essentially you need to add a Reshape layer with the target shape before concatenating:

```
model_2 = Reshape(new_shape)(model_2)
```

This will return `(batch_size, (new_shape))`
You can of course Reshape either branch of your network, just using model_2 output as it is a simpler example

Having said that, maybe it's worth rethinking your network structure. In particular, this problem stems from the second dot layer (which gives you 16 scalars only). As such it's hard to reshape so that the two branches match.

Without knowing what the model is trying to predict or what the training data looks like, it's hard to comment on whether two dots are necessary or not, but potentially re-structuring will solve this issue.

Comment: thanks, i get the error. AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'reshape' Also, why reshape model_output_2

Comment: can you add a snippet of how you implemented Reshape layer in the comments here?
either reshape will be absolutely fine, just thought it might be easier as Dense has a simpler output

Comment: thanks, model_2 =  Reshape((None, 64))(Dense(64, activation='sigmoid')(model_2)) is not working

Comment: ok the problem is with the parameters passed; basically, it's only expecting target_shape, so you need to modify your code to: model_2 = Reshape(target_shape)(model_2)

Comment: So, its (1, 64) in the reshape?

Comment: should be, but it looks like there is an issue with the second dot layer; basically this changes the (None, 16) output of the previous product to (16, 1). if you remove the second dot, you don't need to reshape. if you need the second dot, you have to really understand what each layer outputs. for example Reshape with change the output to (batch_size, (new_shape)). does this work with your model structure? it looks like some of the bugs are a problem with the network structure itself